# eks jenkins docker dind to build multi-arch java

Tags: docker, jenkins, eks, multi-arch

Is it possible using EKS 1.26 and running Jenkins inside to utilize docker inside docker DIND and runtime containerd (this part already works) and then to produce multi-arch java images (arm64/amd64) with a pipeline through the dind?
I saw a lot of references about using buildx but nothing about it in the jenkins docker plugin?
I see now that buildx is available based on this https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/349
Does it mean I should stop trying to make it work with the plugin and look for straight usage of the cli or even that is not feasible?
The main goal of the question is to understand if that is possible or not and any guidance/references would be of a great help.